# Help me select an option to generate 25 kHz PWM

Tags: arduino, pwm, motor-controller, pll

I'm running Arduino Mega with [Marlin Firmware](https://github.com/MarlinFirmware) (as my 3d printer controller) which to my understanding has its PWM set to 1 kHz.

I want to control a 4-wire fan ([Pfc0612de](https://www.delta-fan.com/pfc0612de-f00.html)) with PWM from 30% to 100% and **to reduce noise** I've decided to use the manufacturer's recommended 25 kHz (I won't need to read the tacho).

[image]
[image]

I don't think I need to worry about phase and only need to control the duty cycle and frequency(?)

After searching I came up with a couple of options but I don't know which is easier or more plausible so here I am

1. Change Mega's timer:

   I don't know If there are any unused timers by Marlin or not, and if there are any, is it possible without affecting its other functionalities?
2. Use a standalone driver with 25 kHz output like MAX31790 (which I can't source, any alternatives?):

   I'll have to send Marlin's fan control commands through I2c
3. Use PLL frequency multiplier from 1 to 25 kHz

   (I don't know if PLL preserves the duty cycle or not):

   3.1. 4046 with divide by 25 (2 MOD-5 7490) (0.3$ + 2x0.5$= 1.3$)

   3.2. LM565 with divide by 25 (2 MOD-5 7490) (4$ + 2x0.5$= 5$) (don't know if it's better than 4046 or not)
4. Use another MCU (Attiny85 or ATmega328) to read the 1 kHz PWM and generate 25 kHz PWM accordingly (4$):

   With the same price as 3.2, I'll have unused pins for 2 more fans?

Any help/guidance would be appreciated

Comment: If you consider external stuff, you could even go for a true analog voltage (equivalent of infinite freq pwm as far as fan is concerned) output device.  Most common setting is 16MHz/64/256 ~=.976 kHz.  You could turn the 64 to 8 for 7.8 kHz or 1 for 62.1kHz (which is better than the 25kHz).  There will be vast consequences to your other users of the timer such as stepper motors.  You could also bit bang and it will have consequences everywhere due to processor cycle consumption.

Comment: you have the source, change the PWM frequency.

Comment: @Jasen, yeah thanks. I just figured out timer3 and 5 are not used by the Marlin firmware

Answer (score 1):

If it's a one-off project for yourself, not in a company with business overheads, I'd definitely choose option 4:

- *Use another MCU (Attiny85 or ATmega328) to read the 1 kHz PWM and generate 25 kHz PWM accordingly (4$)*

If you're happy to write the software, which has a straightforward algorithm, it gives you a low chip count and cost.

Given it's slightly vague spec' on your fan's PWM input, it also gives you the maximum flexibility to cope with any discoveries about your fan. The spec' covers the PWM input but in the minimum detail.

Comment: ok, thanks. which MCU would you suggest?

Comment: @Sia_Sh, part recommendations are off-topic for the site but, with the current chip shortages, it's even more a choice for you to make. Use a supplier website's part selector - almost any MCU will do it so go on price, package and single-chipness. Once you've chosen, look up if you can get free software development tools for it. It's straightforward and probably the least work to solve your problem.

Answer (score -2):

For an easy solution, I suggest you take your low freq pwm and shove it through a low pass filter (spec sheet has a transistor at point 14 that would be a nice place to put a powered low pass filter-buffer circuit!).  Output should be a near analog voltage that you can feed to the fan controller in place of pwm.  Since you just want to control speed, this would get you better results than high frequency pwm.

As TonyM pointed out in the comments, there's a pesky "IC" in the middle.  You can bypass the part on point 14 of the spec sheet that makes an automatic on feature for this and feed analog to the left part of it.  Try it with a potentiometer before disabling that little 5V transistor for good and replacing with a buffer.

Comment: No, the fan specified by the OP is **designed** to have its speed controlled by a PWM signal. It will not accept an analog input.

Comment: Have you even tried putting an analog signal to it?  Computer fans "designed" to take a PWM signal also accept analog.  Design to accept pwm generally involves placing a filter on the pwm signal (inductor of the motor can be used as an integrated component for this)

Comment: @Abel, on fans, CPU fans are a fan with a brushless motor control IC in it. The PWM doesn't go straight to a motor but into the control IC. So no analogue control voltage, must be PWM. Here, this fan's much larger but the datasheet states PWM.

Comment: @Abel, it specifies 30-300k Hz but recommends 25 kHz in the datasheet for the PWM line. or do you mean I should use the analog voltage to power the fan?

Comment: It depends on what you are comfortable with.  If you can rewrite marlin (mostly stepper timers and any analog reading), you can set all clock divisors to 1.  If you can buy a 12V DC motor controller that likes the low freq Arduino pwm, you can just use the fan as a 2-wire (one directional- do not wire this one backwards) DC motor.  If you have circuit components handy and know enough to mod their "IC" you can make it accept the Arduino pwm.  Could also swap over to esp32 marlin from Arduino.  Many ways to skin this cat